# Is there a way to make the tab order honour the visual order?

Tags: html, css, tab-ordering

Let's say I have a web page which contains a list of links.

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Alpha</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bravo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Charlie</a></li>
</ul>
```

For design reasons, I need to change the order of these links on larger screens so that "Alpha" is visually at the bottom of the list.

```
@media (min-width: 30em) {

    .links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .links > li:first-child {
        order: 1;
    }

}
```

When tabbing through the various focusable elements on the page, the visual order of these links is not honoured, thus when tabbing through the list the focus order will be "Alpha" then "Bravo" then "Charlie".

If I set a positive `tabindex` on any of those links, they are moved to the end of the tab order (since all other focusable elements essentially have a tab index of `0`).

My question is: **is there a way to make the tab order honour the visual order?**.

Comment: Probably not. Unless you specify a positive value for `tabindex` the focus will follow the DOM and not really care about whatever CSS you apply to move things around. I'd create a separate element with the right order and hide it on desktop / mobile.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-accessibility

Comment: @jeanpaulxiao nice find. If you provide an answer that basically says "according to the specs, no" and include that link, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: So what you need to do is move it using script... and if without script you can duplicate the item and toggle display values.

Comment: @René I think you're right. The only solution seems to be to adjust the markup rather than simply the styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to united flex ordering and HTML ordering,
according to https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property and section 5.4.1. Reordering and Accessibility:

> Authors must use order only for visual, not logical, reordering of content. Style sheets that use order to perform logical reordering are non-conforming.